# Windows 10 upgrade vanished my Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, windows, uefi

Recently I upgraded my HP Stream 200-010 Mini Desktop from windows 8.1 to windows 10.
Before the upgrade I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on an 80GB external hard drive connected with usb.
For log in I always pressed the Esc key, pressed F9 for boot device options and then choosed Ubuntu from the boot order menu.
Probably there is an easier way but I'm not a technical expert and I barely managed to perform the installation so that was enough for me.
Anyway after the upgrade the Ubuntu option disappeared from the boot order menu (I was trying the same method with the Esc key...).
After searching the web I tried to solve the problem with "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi" command but it didn't solve the problem and even damaged the windows boot manager - every startup i received weird message that delayed login few minutes until eventually I refreshed windows.
Hope I was able to explain my problem so someone can help me

Thanks

Additional Information that might help:
On the disk management i can see the external hard drive with the partitions
I didn't change any settings like secure boot or fast startup (also before the upgrade)
I still have the bootable USB stick

I am not sure, after I installed Ubuntu and try to boot I did saw purple screen with about 3 rows which the word grub appears.
The thing is, from what I've read and I understood (again I am far from being an expert) if I will change the uefi boot source and drag the usb hard drive option to be highest the boot will start with ubuntu since it installed on the external usb hard drive and when I will choose to disconnect the hard drive the windows 8.1 will boot first
But unfortunately it never works that way- I got the purple screen that I mentioned and I could not get out of it so I restart the pc and work with the boot menu screen...

My Windows Boot Manager now working ok but only after I refreshed windows.
after i run the bcdedit command I had problems.

Comment: Let me confirm a few things before I start: 1. You installed Ubuntu on another drive. 2. You upgraded Windows 10. Now, did you ever get to see grub before the update or did you always log in using the Boot Menu screen? And is your Windows Boot Manager now working ok without any errors?

Comment: Get `boot-repair` from the Ubuntu website, burn it to a USB stick and boot from it to fix Ubuntu.

Comment: Reinstall grub from an ubuntu live session USB or disk.

Answer (score 1):

In an EFI boot, boot loaders are ordinary files on a partition known as the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) These files can, in principle, be stored under any filename in any location on any ESP. (You can have multiple ESPs.) Thus, an EFI stores information on what boot loader to use in NVRAM. It sounds like your NVRAM entry for Ubuntu was lost or damaged.

One possible cause of this problem is if the disk is disconnected; some EFIs look for boot loaders described in NVRAM and, if an entry describes a non-existent file, delete that entry. This is fine most of the time, but if you disconnect a disk, any boot loaders it contains will become unreachable the next time you boot the computer. You didn't mention disconnecting your external Ubuntu-containing disk when you did your upgrade, but this practice is fairly common, so I can't help but think you might have done so, and your firmware therefore deleted the relevant entry.

If this was the cause, there are a number of solutions:

- **Re-create the old entry** -- You can use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows or `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu to re-create your old NVRAM entry. In either case, you'll need to locate the old GRUB and tell the utility where to find it. This will be easier with EasyUEFI, which is a GUI tool; `efibootmgr` is a command-line program. You'll need to identify your ESP(s) and figure out on which one GRUB resides. ESPs are FAT partitions, so you should use GParted, `parted`, `blkid`, or some similar tool (in Ubuntu; or Windows equivalents) to identify ESP candidates and locate GRUB. On any given disk, the ESP is usually (but not always) the first or second partition. Note that, if GRUB has an entry for Windows, once it becomes the default, you should be able to select Windows from the GRUB menu. OTOH, if GRUB is on your external disk, unplugging it could re-create your current problem.
- **Rename GRUB** -- Instead of re-creating the NVRAM entry, you can skip it by giving GRUB the "fallback" filename of `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. This filename is used on removable media like OS installers, the idea being that the firmware needs a standardized filename to boot from removable disks that it's never before used. If you give GRUB the fallback filename, your computer should be able to boot GRUB from your external disk as if it were an OS installer. You'll need to use your firmware's built-in boot manager (as you seem to have been doing until now) to select which OS to boot.
- **Use a more flexible boot manager on your hard disk** -- You can install a boot manager that actively searches for available boot loaders on your hard disk. I know of two that do this: the now-abandoned [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) and my currently-maintained fork of it, [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) If you install either of these *to your internal hard disk's ESP,* it should detect and enable you to launch GRUB (or even your Linux kernels directly, in the case of rEFInd) on your external disk. You can test rEFInd by using the CD-R or USB flash drive version, and if it works, install rEFInd to the ESP on your internal disk.

Some of these solutions may work even if I've mis-diagnosed the cause of your problem, but that really depends on what the real problem is. One critical question is: Where is GRUB installed? If it's on the same ESP as the Windows boot loader, the cause is likely something other than what I'm speculating about, and you could set up that GRUB to be the primary boot program and it *should* work pretty well. If GRUB is on a separate ESP on the external disk, you'll have to pay careful attention to which ESP is which no matter what you do.